# Delete first element of vector and reduce it's size by 1

Tags: c++, vector

Say I have

```
std::vector<int> xVec{ 1, 2, 3 };
```

and I want to remove its first element, leaving `xVec` with `{ 2, 3 }`

To accomplish this, I tried `xVec.erase( xVec.begin() )`, but that left me with `{ 2, 3, 3 }`.
It erased the first element but left the vector the same size.  Plus it repeats the last element.

What can I do to delete the first vector element and reduce the vector size?

Comment: I think you're reusing the iterator.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5ec0ffc2520ffd5

Comment: Huh that's odd, it should work. Would you mind showing an example?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I guess the loop that print the vector is doing out-of-bound access. UB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is not caused by the size of vector, but you still try to print the third element after you already removed the first element, which I can reproduce it by:

```
std::vector<int> x({1,2,3});
int size=x.size():
x.erase(x.begin());
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    std::cout << x[i] << ' ';
```

Note that accessing index outside the size of vector causes undefined behavior, which the x[2] does not necessary equal to the last element